# Are there natural numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, such that $x^4+y^4-2^{3z}=3$?

Tags: exponentiation, natural-numbers

Are there natural numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, such that $x^4+y^4-2^{3z}=3$? Justify!!

I literally have no idea for this problem. I thought of doing the last digit but it doesnt help at all. I wonder if we can write $x^4+y^4$ as a product of two terms of something like this.
I think using modulo can help solving this problem, but I don't get to any good idea.

Please help me!!

Comment: As we commented yesterday, modulo $4$ is also enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough reputation to comment.

Try looking at the equation modulo $8$.

Notice that $2^{3z}$ is divisible by $8$, so you would get that the sum of two fourth powers gives the residue $3$ mod $8$.

Comment: I understand the idea, but I wonder how i show that $x^4$ modulo $8$ is $0 or 1$?

Comment: If $x$ is even, then $2^4 = 16$ divides $x^4$, so it is also divisible by $0$ and the residue is $0$. If $x$ is odd, then $x$ is congruent to $1$,$3$,$5$ or $7$ modulo $8$. By taking the fourth power of each of these modulo $8$, you can see that $x^4$ is congruent to $1$ in this case.